# Are code pages and code charts the same thing?

Tags: character-encoding, character

Based on what I have gathered so far from reading information available online:

- **character set** is a bunch of characters that we want to use (like an interface)
- **character encoding** is a method of encoding some character set (like an implementation)

What is the relationship between code charts and code pages and how do they fit into the overall context? I am not sure if these two terms are synonyms or if they are referring to distinct concepts.

Do code charts/code pages define character sets through large tables and also provide a method of encoding, making them a part of character encoding? Or, do they only define character sets and leave encoding implementation to another aspect? Additionally, is a locale simply a type of code chart/code page or is it a separate concept altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the majority of cases, character sets and character encodings are one and the same. For example, ISO-8859-1 defines the character set for Western Europe AND the encoding using an 8bit scheme.

See the specification for ISO-8859-1: ftp://std.dkuug.dk/JTC1/sc2/wg3/docs/n411.pdf, which includes the encoding implementation.

Unicode on the other hand separates encoding from the character definition, albeit within a bunch of related documents. In Unicode, just about all current and a good deal of historic characters, symbols and modifiers are mapped to a 32 bit "code point". Encodings of UTF-32, UTF-16 and UTF-8 are then documented separately, to define how the Unicode Code Point is encoded.

Comment: is code chart a synonym for code page? Or am I all the way left field, and you have never even heard of the term code chart

Comment: No. "Code chart" isn't a popular term, except from Unicode.org to describe the maps, which are encoding agnostic. "Code page" encompasses the encoding.

Comment: Just to clarify, "code page" is a term stemming from IBM/Windows that often just refers to supported character encodings, right?

Comment: IMHO, "code page" is often used to refer to 8bit character sets on IBM and Windows platforms.